# Programming in R: Change column data type from character (with $) to numeric

Tags: r

I am cleaning a data frame for analysis in R. One of the columns contains the variable "price" and it is in character(chr) with $ symbol. I need it in numeric (dbl).

Below is the code I got. When I check the table, the rows are replaced with "N/A". Please let me know what went wrong and if there is a better code for this. Thanks!

```
rental_df <- rental_df %>%
       mutate(location = sub(".*in ", "", location)) %>%
       price_1 = mutate_at(price, as.numeric) %>% 
       clean_names()
```

[Before Cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmCjh.jpg)

[After Cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8htx.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but if you use mutate(price=as.numeric(price)) it should work.

Comment: You need to include the table here

Comment: you're saying it looks like "$19.99" ? you need to sub out the $ before coercing to numeric

Comment: Yes. It looks like "$19.99". After I mutate it shows "N/A".

Comment: How do I sub it? I tried adding => sub("$", "", rental_df["price"])  in my pipes, but it doesn't work. The price column is the 9th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to replace the dollar sign.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

rental_df <- tibble(
  location = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 200),
  price = paste0("$", round(runif(1000, min = 2000, max = 4000)))
)
```

```r
head(rental_df, 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   location price
#>   <chr>    <chr>
#> 1 A        $2531
#> 2 B        $2744
#> 3 C        $3146
#> 4 D        $3816
#> 5 E        $2403
```

```r
rental_df %>%
  mutate(price = as.numeric(gsub("[$]", "", price))) %>%
  head(. , 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   location price
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A         2531
#> 2 B         2744
#> 3 C         3146
#> 4 D         3816
#> 5 E         2403
```

`sub` could also work since there should just be one dollar sign, you were probably just missing the square brackets.

```r
rental_df %>%
  mutate(price = as.numeric(sub("[$]", "", price))) %>%
  head(. , 5)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   location price
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A         2531
#> 2 B         2744
#> 3 C         3146
#> 4 D         3816
#> 5 E         2403
```

I'm sure you've checked, but as an aside make sure `sub` is doing what you expect when modifying `location`. `sub` replaces the first instance while `gsub` replaces all.

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It was the square brackets!!! Thank you so much for showing me the different ways of doing it. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @Hayley That's great, I'm glad it solved it! Could you please mark this as the answer so that way everyone will know it's resolved. I believe we both get a bit of reputation as well.

Comment: @TraningPizza Got it! Thank you again for your thorough reply.